# Mounting Amazon EFS to exising folder in ES2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Instructions of how to attach Amazon Elastic File System says to create new directory efs and then mount to that directory using commands we can get in "Attach" window of ESF UI.

I am trying to access very large file in my ES2 instance using EFS. Coping that large file from existing folder to efs has not been successful task.

Is it possible to attach ESF to existing folder instead of folder efs?